# Spring JPA Query of a single column result into a generic type?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am relatively new to Spring-Boot and JPA. I've been doing pretty well with Entities and Repositories for complex/multi-column tables, but I have a view that I need to query which has only 2 columns, the key/index (Long) and a Date.

I would like to be able to add a method to an existing Repository that can query this date based on the key, and return a single LocalDate result rather than an @Entity result.  Can this be done?

Bonus questions:

1) I'd like to have the java.sql.Date converted to a java.time.LocalDate. Is it possible to have this conversion within the Query since there is no Entity/Column to assign the Conversion to?

2) Is it possible to also define a query that returns a `Map<Long, LocalDate>`?

Comment: I think I missed making my point-- I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require defining a new `@Entity` or `@Repository`.  It seems silly to me to write a dozen lines and a couple new files just to get a Date from a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a working solution.

I simply added to an *existing `@Repository`*:

```
@Query(value = "select COMPLETED_DATE from COMPLETION_DATES where ID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
LocalDate getCompletedDateById(Long id);
```

I had previously defined a `LocalDateConverter` which had the `@Converter(autoApply = true`) annotation, which appears to have handled the conversion for me (it just works).

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Repository with annotation @NoRepositoryBean. You can define generic view using this annotation.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ViewRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
   T findOne(ID id);
   boolean exists(ID id);
   Iterable<T> findAll();
   long count();
}
```

You can extend generic view repository and specify the View class.

```
public interface MyViewRepository extends ViewRepository<MyView, Long> {
}
```

Define view class

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "my_view")
 public class MyView implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Long key;
        private LocalDate value;
 }
```

You question answers.

1. You just define the type LocalDate in your view.
2. You have to write Spring Convertor for getting Map. Instead of Map you can get `List<MyView>`